# How can i create message box using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3. I am just unable to create message box which should have 4 rows inside. can anyone please help me? My code is below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <h5><label for="inputName">Name</label></h5>

                <input type="text" name="career[name]" class="form-control" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter your name" pattern="[a-zA-Z. ]{1,50}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <h5><label for="inputEmail">Email</label></h5>

                <input type="email" name="career[email]" class="form-control" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <h5><label for="inputMobile">Mobile</label></h5>

                <input type="tel" name="career[mobile]" class="form-control" tabindex="3" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <h5><label for="inputMessage">Message</label></h5>

                <input type="text" name="career[message]" class="form-control" tabindex="4" placeholder="Write your details" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" tabindex="5">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my message box something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are not using `textarea`! Replace the below code:

```
<input type="text" name="career[message]" class="form-control" tabindex="4" 
       placeholder="Write your details" required>
```

With:

```
<textarea name="career[message]" class="form-control" tabindex="4"
          placeholder="Write your details" required></textarea>
```